# Android Countries list with flags and availability of getting iso mobile codes

Tags: android, iso, mobile-country-code

Needed Example of project showing all countries with flags and availability for getting countries mobile codes.

Comment: What do you mean by "availability for getting countries mobile codes"? The number of country flags supported by each version of Android has increased from none, to ten, to over two hundred. Whether older versions of Android can display the flags even with newer fonts I can't tell you but there may be an OS issue preventing it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We need files with codes described below.

class **MainActivity**

```
package com.example.countrieswithflags;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] recourseList=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(new CountriesListAdapter(this, recourseList));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

We need an adapter for list

**CountriesListAdapter**

```
package com.example.countrieswithflags;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountriesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public CountriesListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.country_list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewCountryName);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewFlag);

        String[] g=values[position].split(",");
        textView.setText(GetCountryZipCode(g[1]).trim());


        String pngName = g[1].trim().toLowerCase();
        imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + pngName, null, context.getPackageName()));
        return rowView;
    }

    private String GetCountryZipCode(String ssid){
        Locale loc = new Locale("", ssid);

        return loc.getDisplayCountry().trim();
    }
}
```

Our **strings.xml** will have these lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Countries With Flags</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <string-array name="CountryCodes" >
        <item>93,AF</item>
        <item>355,AL</item>
        <item>213,DZ</item>
        <item>376,AD</item>
        <item>244,AO</item>
        <item>54,AR</item>
        <item>374,AM</item>
        <item>297,AW</item>
        <item>61,AU</item>
        <item>43,AT</item>
        <item>994,AZ</item>
        <item>973,BH</item>
        <item>880,BD</item>
        <item>375,BY</item>
        <item>32,BE</item>
        <item>501,BZ</item>
        <item>229,BJ</item>
        <item>975,BT</item>
        <item>591,BO</item>
        <item>387,BA</item>
        <item>267,BW</item>
        <item>55,BR</item>
        <item>673,BN</item>
        <item>359,BG</item>
        <item>226,BF</item>
        <item>95,MM</item>
        <item>257,BI</item>
        <item>855,KH</item>
        <item>237,CM</item>
        <item>1,CA</item>
        <item>238,CV</item>
        <item>236,CF</item>
        <item>235,TD</item>
        <item>56,CL</item>
        <item>86,CN</item>
        <item>61,CX</item>
        <item>61,CC</item>
        <item>57,CO</item>
        <item>269,KM</item>
        <item>242,CG</item>
        <item>243,CD</item>
        <item>682,CK</item>
        <item>506,CR</item>
        <item>385,HR</item>
        <item>53,CU</item>
        <item>357,CY</item>
        <item>420,CZ</item>
        <item>45,DK</item>
        <item>253,DJ</item>
        <item>670,TL</item>
        <item>593,EC</item>
        <item>20,EG</item>
        <item>503,SV</item>
        <item>240,GQ</item>
        <item>291,ER</item>
        <item>372,EE</item>
        <item>251,ET</item>
        <item>500,FK</item>
        <item>298,FO</item>
        <item>679,FJ</item>
        <item>358,FI</item>
        <item>33,FR</item>
        <item>689,PF</item>
        <item>241,GA</item>
        <item>220,GM</item>
        <item>995,GE</item>
        <item>49,DE</item>
        <item>233,GH</item>
        <item>350,GI</item>
        <item>30,GR</item>
        <item>299,GL</item>
        <item>502,GT</item>
        <item>224,GN</item>
        <item>245,GW</item>
        <item>592,GY</item>
        <item>509,HT</item>
        <item>504,HN</item>
        <item>852,HK</item>
        <item>36,HU</item>
        <item>91,IN</item>
        <item>62,ID</item>
        <item>98,IR</item>
        <item>964,IQ</item>
        <item>353,IE</item>
        <item>44,IM</item>
        <item>972,IL</item>
        <item>39,IT</item>
        <item>225,CI</item>
        <item>81,JP</item>
        <item>962,JO</item>
        <item>7,KZ</item>
        <item>254,KE</item>
        <item>686,KI</item>
        <item>965,KW</item>
        <item>996,KG</item>
        <item>856,LA</item>
        <item>371,LV</item>
        <item>961,LB</item>
        <item>266,LS</item>
        <item>231,LR</item>
        <item>218,LY</item>
        <item>423,LI</item>
        <item>370,LT</item>
        <item>352,LU</item>
        <item>853,MO</item>
        <item>389,MK</item>
        <item>261,MG</item>
        <item>265,MW</item>
        <item>60,MY</item>
        <item>960,MV</item>
        <item>223,ML</item>
        <item>356,MT</item>
        <item>692,MH</item>
        <item>222,MR</item>
        <item>230,MU</item>
        <item>262,YT</item>
        <item>52,MX</item>
        <item>691,FM</item>
        <item>373,MD</item>
        <item>377,MC</item>
        <item>976,MN</item>
        <item>382,ME</item>
        <item>212,MA</item>
        <item>258,MZ</item>
        <item>264,NA</item>
        <item>674,NR</item>
        <item>977,NP</item>
        <item>31,NL</item>
        <item>599,AN</item>
        <item>687,NC</item>
        <item>64,NZ</item>
        <item>505,NI</item>
        <item>227,NE</item>
        <item>234,NG</item>
        <item>683,NU</item>
        <item>850,KP</item>
        <item>47,NO</item>
        <item>968,OM</item>
        <item>92,PK</item>
        <item>680,PW</item>
        <item>507,PA</item>
        <item>675,PG</item>
        <item>595,PY</item>
        <item>51,PE</item>
        <item>63,PH</item>
        <item>870,PN</item>
        <item>48,PL</item>
        <item>351,PT</item>
        <item>1,PR</item>
        <item>974,QA</item>
        <item>40,RO</item>
        <item>7,RU</item>
        <item>250,RW</item>
        <item>590,BL</item>
        <item>685,WS</item>
        <item>378,SM</item>
        <item>239,ST</item>
        <item>966,SA</item>
        <item>221,SN</item>
        <item>381,RS</item>
        <item>248,SC</item>
        <item>232,SL</item>
        <item>65,SG</item>
        <item>421,SK</item>
        <item>386,SI</item>
        <item>677,SB</item>
        <item>252,SO</item>
        <item>27,ZA</item>
        <item>82,KR</item>
        <item>34,ES</item>
        <item>94,LK</item>
        <item>290,SH</item>
        <item>508,PM</item>
        <item>249,SD</item>
        <item>597,SR</item>
        <item>268,SZ</item>
        <item>46,SE</item>
        <item>41,CH</item>
        <item>963,SY</item>
        <item>886,TW</item>
        <item>992,TJ</item>
        <item>255,TZ</item>
        <item>66,TH</item>
        <item>228,TG</item>
        <item>690,TK</item>
        <item>676,TO</item>
        <item>216,TN</item>
        <item>90,TR</item>
        <item>993,TM</item>
        <item>688,TV</item>
        <item>971,AE</item>
        <item>256,UG</item>
        <item>44,GB</item>
        <item>380,UA</item>
        <item>598,UY</item>
        <item>1,US</item>
        <item>998,UZ</item>
        <item>678,VU</item>
        <item>39,VA</item>
        <item>58,VE</item>
        <item>84,VN</item>
        <item>681,WF</item>
        <item>967,YE</item>
        <item>260,ZM</item>
        <item>263,ZW</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

in the layout we must have **country_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgViewFlag"
        android:layout_height="11px"
        android:layout_width="16px"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtViewCountryName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and **activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >


    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Also**  You can find images of flags with correct names (iso names of countries) from [here](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/ISO-3166-Country-Codes.htm). Or You can find them in the project(link given above).

Comment: Thanks much for the sample, but... why RAR?

Comment: )) I'll upload unrared version in github

Comment: That is a great solution! thank you very much.

The download link is broken

Comment: Thank you @AlonKogan, did't find time for putting it in GitHub.

Comment: How to do square shape emoji flag?

Comment: @NitinKarale have you found solution to do square shape emoji flag?

Comment: @RiteshAdulkar No