# Get emoji flag by country code

Tags: java, android

There is a list of countries codes, I need to attach emoji flag to each one. 
Is there a way to extract unicode from it or find emoji for country code?

This npm example looks similar for my goal (but uses hexadecimal as input) https://github.com/thekelvinliu/country-code-emoji/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: What do you mean `it uses hex as input`? This method takes a String, `throw new TypeError('argument must be a string');` What is the problem you are having? Whay can you not just rewrite this in Java, if that is your usecase, it seems like all you need from here is the offset from 0 to the first unicode character.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This code snippet worked for me. Just replace `"US"` with whichever valid country code (based on the Regional Indicator Symbol Let­ters) you like and it will create a String `flag` containing the flag emoji for that country. ([Reference](http://emojipedia.org/flags/))

```
int flagOffset = 0x1F1E6;
int asciiOffset = 0x41;

String country = "US";

int firstChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 0) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
int secondChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 1) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;

String flag = new String(Character.toChars(firstChar))
            + new String(Character.toChars(secondChar));
```

[This answer helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35849652/3550988)

Comment: how to do square shape emoji country flag?

Comment: @NitinKarale You should create a new question rather than using a comment.  The short answer though is that you can't control that.

Comment: I like this approach, but I need this functionality in Angular and JavaScript/TypeScript do not have the same functions for characters; is this also possible for Angular?

Comment: @TorstenN. you have to do another question. SO is not a forum.

Comment: Convert [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) to Flag emoji using Kotlin functions. Open [gist](https://gist.github.com/asissuthar/cf8fcf0b3be968b1f341e537eb423163)

Answer (score 7):

```
function getFlags($code){
    $code = strtoupper($code);
    if($code == 'AD') return '';
    if($code == 'AE') return '';
    if($code == 'AF') return '';
    if($code == 'AG') return '';
    if($code == 'AI') return '';
    if($code == 'AL') return '';
    if($code == 'AM') return '';
    if($code == 'AO') return '';
    if($code == 'AQ') return '';
    if($code == 'AR') return '';
    if($code == 'AS') return '';
    if($code == 'AT') return '';
    if($code == 'AU') return '';
    if($code == 'AW') return '';
    if($code == 'AX') return '';
    if($code == 'AZ') return '';
    if($code == 'BA') return '';
    if($code == 'BB') return '';
    if($code == 'BD') return '';
    if($code == 'BE') return '';
    if($code == 'BF') return '';
    if($code == 'BG') return '';
    if($code == 'BH') return '';
    if($code == 'BI') return '';
    if($code == 'BJ') return '';
    if($code == 'BL') return '';
    if($code == 'BM') return '';
    if($code == 'BN') return '';
    if($code == 'BO') return '';
    if($code == 'BQ') return '';
    if($code == 'BR') return '';
    if($code == 'BS') return '';
    if($code == 'BT') return '';
    if($code == 'BV') return '';
    if($code == 'BW') return '';
    if($code == 'BY') return '';
    if($code == 'BZ') return '';
    if($code == 'CA') return '';
    if($code == 'CC') return '';
    if($code == 'CD') return '';
    if($code == 'CF') return '';
    if($code == 'CG') return '';
    if($code == 'CH') return '';
    if($code == 'CI') return '';
    if($code == 'CK') return '';
    if($code == 'CL') return '';
    if($code == 'CM') return '';
    if($code == 'CN') return '';
    if($code == 'CO') return '';
    if($code == 'CR') return '';
    if($code == 'CU') return '';
    if($code == 'CV') return '';
    if($code == 'CW') return '';
    if($code == 'CX') return '';
    if($code == 'CY') return '';
    if($code == 'CZ') return '';
    if($code == 'DE') return '';
    if($code == 'DJ') return '';
    if($code == 'DK') return '';
    if($code == 'DM') return '';
    if($code == 'DO') return '';
    if($code == 'DZ') return '';
    if($code == 'EC') return '';
    if($code == 'EE') return '';
    if($code == 'EG') return '';
    if($code == 'EH') return '';
    if($code == 'ER') return '';
    if($code == 'ES') return '';
    if($code == 'ET') return '';
    if($code == 'FI') return '';
    if($code == 'FJ') return '';
    if($code == 'FK') return '';
    if($code == 'FM') return '';
    if($code == 'FO') return '';
    if($code == 'FR') return '';
    if($code == 'GA') return '';
    if($code == 'GB') return '';
    if($code == 'GD') return '';
    if($code == 'GE') return '';
    if($code == 'GF') return '';
    if($code == 'GG') return '';
    if($code == 'GH') return '';
    if($code == 'GI') return '';
    if($code == 'GL') return '';
    if($code == 'GM') return '';
    if($code == 'GN') return '';
    if($code == 'GP') return '';
    if($code == 'GQ') return '';
    if($code == 'GR') return '';
    if($code == 'GS') return '';
    if($code == 'GT') return '';
    if($code == 'GU') return '';
    if($code == 'GW') return '';
    if($code == 'GY') return '';
    if($code == 'HK') return '';
    if($code == 'HM') return '';
    if($code == 'HN') return '';
    if($code == 'HR') return '';
    if($code == 'HT') return '';
    if($code == 'HU') return '';
    if($code == 'ID') return '';
    if($code == 'IE') return '';
    if($code == 'IL') return '';
    if($code == 'IM') return '';
    if($code == 'IN') return '';
    if($code == 'IO') return '';
    if($code == 'IQ') return '';
    if($code == 'IR') return '';
    if($code == 'IS') return '';
    if($code == 'IT') return '';
    if($code == 'JE') return '';
    if($code == 'JM') return '';
    if($code == 'JO') return '';
    if($code == 'JP') return '';
    if($code == 'KE') return '';
    if($code == 'KG') return '';
    if($code == 'KH') return '';
    if($code == 'KI') return '';
    if($code == 'KM') return '';
    if($code == 'KN') return '';
    if($code == 'KP') return '';
    if($code == 'KR') return '';
    if($code == 'KW') return '';
    if($code == 'KY') return '';
    if($code == 'KZ') return '';
    if($code == 'LA') return '';
    if($code == 'LB') return '';
    if($code == 'LC') return '';
    if($code == 'LI') return '';
    if($code == 'LK') return '';
    if($code == 'LR') return '';
    if($code == 'LS') return '';
    if($code == 'LT') return '';
    if($code == 'LU') return '';
    if($code == 'LV') return '';
    if($code == 'LY') return '';
    if($code == 'MA') return '';
    if($code == 'MC') return '';
    if($code == 'MD') return '';
    if($code == 'ME') return '';
    if($code == 'MF') return '';
    if($code == 'MG') return '';
    if($code == 'MH') return '';
    if($code == 'MK') return '';
    if($code == 'ML') return '';
    if($code == 'MM') return '';
    if($code == 'MN') return '';
    if($code == 'MO') return '';
    if($code == 'MP') return '';
    if($code == 'MQ') return '';
    if($code == 'MR') return '';
    if($code == 'MS') return '';
    if($code == 'MT') return '';
    if($code == 'MU') return '';
    if($code == 'MV') return '';
    if($code == 'MW') return '';
    if($code == 'MX') return '';
    if($code == 'MY') return '';
    if($code == 'MZ') return '';
    if($code == 'NA') return '';
    if($code == 'NC') return '';
    if($code == 'NE') return '';
    if($code == 'NF') return '';
    if($code == 'NG') return '';
    if($code == 'NI') return '';
    if($code == 'NL') return '';
    if($code == 'NO') return '';
    if($code == 'NP') return '';
    if($code == 'NR') return '';
    if($code == 'NU') return '';
    if($code == 'NZ') return '';
    if($code == 'OM') return '';
    if($code == 'PA') return '';
    if($code == 'PE') return '';
    if($code == 'PF') return '';
    if($code == 'PG') return '';
    if($code == 'PH') return '';
    if($code == 'PK') return '';
    if($code == 'PL') return '';
    if($code == 'PM') return '';
    if($code == 'PN') return '';
    if($code == 'PR') return '';
    if($code == 'PS') return '';
    if($code == 'PT') return '';
    if($code == 'PW') return '';
    if($code == 'PY') return '';
    if($code == 'QA') return '';
    if($code == 'RE') return '';
    if($code == 'RO') return '';
    if($code == 'RS') return '';
    if($code == 'RU') return '';
    if($code == 'RW') return '';
    if($code == 'SA') return '';
    if($code == 'SB') return '';
    if($code == 'SC') return '';
    if($code == 'SD') return '';
    if($code == 'SE') return '';
    if($code == 'SG') return '';
    if($code == 'SH') return '';
    if($code == 'SI') return '';
    if($code == 'SJ') return '';
    if($code == 'SK') return '';
    if($code == 'SL') return '';
    if($code == 'SM') return '';
    if($code == 'SN') return '';
    if($code == 'SO') return '';
    if($code == 'SR') return '';
    if($code == 'SS') return '';
    if($code == 'ST') return '';
    if($code == 'SV') return '';
    if($code == 'SX') return '';
    if($code == 'SY') return '';
    if($code == 'SZ') return '';
    if($code == 'TC') return '';
    if($code == 'TD') return '';
    if($code == 'TF') return '';
    if($code == 'TG') return '';
    if($code == 'TH') return '';
    if($code == 'TJ') return '';
    if($code == 'TK') return '';
    if($code == 'TL') return '';
    if($code == 'TM') return '';
    if($code == 'TN') return '';
    if($code == 'TO') return '';
    if($code == 'TR') return '';
    if($code == 'TT') return '';
    if($code == 'TV') return '';
    if($code == 'TW') return '';
    if($code == 'TZ') return '';
    if($code == 'UA') return '';
    if($code == 'UG') return '';
    if($code == 'UM') return '';
    if($code == 'US') return '';
    if($code == 'UY') return '';
    if($code == 'UZ') return '';
    if($code == 'VA') return '';
    if($code == 'VC') return '';
    if($code == 'VE') return '';
    if($code == 'VG') return '';
    if($code == 'VI') return '';
    if($code == 'VN') return '';
    if($code == 'VU') return '';
    if($code == 'WF') return '';
    if($code == 'WS') return '';
    if($code == 'XK') return '';
    if($code == 'YE') return '';
    if($code == 'YT') return '';
    if($code == 'ZA') return '';
    if($code == 'ZM') return '';
    return '';
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks it helped me in PHP and JavaScript, but remember this is linear search, so it will not give best performance if it is used heavily.

Comment: @Accountantم doesn't work in that way in a compiled language. In C++ or C# the structure is jumped at evaluation point.

Comment: @Leandro even with short-circuit evaluation it's still a linear search. This is less efficient than, for instance, a hash lookup: O(n) vs O(1) on average. It has nothing to do with whether the language is compiled or interpreted.

Comment: ok guys, you should learn how structures work on base level

Comment: This is really the worst possible solution. Do *not* do this, but use one of the proper code point calculating solutions provided by others.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function getFlagEmoji(countryCode) {
  const codePoints = countryCode.toUpperCase().split("").map((char) => 127397 + char.charCodeAt(0));
  return String.fromCodePoint(...codePoints);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(getFlagEmoji(input.value));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Country Code" maxlength="2" />
<button id="btn">Get Emoji</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone looking for a Unity/C# version...

```
public string GetCountryFlagEmojiFromCode(string countryCode) {

    int flagOffset = 0x1F1E6;
    int asciiOffset = 0x41;

    int firstChar = char.ConvertToUtf32(countryCode, 0) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
    int secondChar = char.ConvertToUtf32(countryCode, 1) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
        
    String flag = char.ConvertFromUtf32(firstChar) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(secondChar);
    return flag;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP I always use this one, calculates the character index with hex2bin:

```php
function parseCountryCodeToFlag(string $code): string
{
    $exceptions = [
        'en' => 'gb',
        'uk' => 'gb',
    ];

    $code = str_replace(array_keys($exceptions), array_values($exceptions), $code);

    $emoji = [];
    foreach(str_split($code) as $c) {
        if(($o = ord($c)) > 64 && $o % 32 < 27) {
            $emoji[] = hex2bin("f09f87" . dechex($o % 32 + 165));
            continue;
        }
        
        $emoji[] = $c;
    }

    return join($emoji);
}
```