# Get emoji flag from country code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, emoji

I want to convert a country code like "US" to an Emoji flag, ie transform "US" string to the appropriate Unicode in Ruby.

[Here's an equivalent example for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235254/18706)

Comment: Convert it, we don't mind.

Comment: Downvote indicates otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a hash: `{ 'US' => '', 'NK' => '', ...}`

Comment: @Stefan Could but it's too much unnecessary code when it can be programmatically generated. Also one can hope platforms will stay up to date with any changes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`tr`](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=Ruby&docset_name=Ruby%202&path=String.html%23method-i-tr&platform=ruby&repo=Main&version=2.5.1) to translate alphabetic characters to their regional indicator symbols:

```
'US'.tr('A-Z', "\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}")
#=> ""
```

Of course, you can also use the Unicode characters directly:

```
'US'.tr('A-Z', '-')
#=> ""
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a port of that to Ruby:

```
country = 'US'
flagOffset = 0x1F1E6
asciiOffset = 0x41
firstChar = country[0].ord - asciiOffset + flagOffset
secondChar = country[1].ord - asciiOffset + flagOffset
flag = [firstChar, secondChar].pack("U*")
```