# Display country flag character in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234666/get-emoji-flag-by-country-code) has some code to convert a locale to a country emoji in Java. I tried implementing it in Dart but no success.

I tried converting the code above to Dart

```
  void _emoji() {
    int flagOffset = 0x1F1E6;
    int asciiOffset = 0x41;

    String country = "US";

    int firstChar = country.codeUnitAt(0) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;
    int secondChar = country.codeUnitAt(1) - asciiOffset + flagOffset;

    String emoji =
        String.fromCharCode(firstChar) + String.fromCharCode(secondChar);
    print(emoji);
  }
```

"US" locale should output ""

Comment: use systemchannels, thats exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted works correctly, i.e. `print(emoji)` successfully prints .

I assume that the real problem you have is that the Flutter [`Text` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) displays it like this:

[image]

It is the US flag, however, I have to agree that it does not look like it when you see it on device as the font size is very small and the flag has a rather high resolution.

You will need to [use a custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) and apply it to your `Text` widget using the following:

```dart
Text(emoji,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: '...',
  ),
)
```

Otherwise, both the conversion and displaying the flags works fine. I believe that they just look different than you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String countryCodeToEmoji(String countryCode) {
  // 0x41 is Letter A
  // 0x1F1E6 is Regional Indicator Symbol Letter A
  // Example :
  // firstLetter U => 20 + 0x1F1E6
  // secondLetter S => 18 + 0x1F1E6
  // See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol
  final int firstLetter = countryCode.toUpperCase().codeUnitAt(0) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
  final int secondLetter = countryCode.toUpperCase().codeUnitAt(1) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
  return String.fromCharCode(firstLetter) + String.fromCharCode(secondLetter);
}
```

usage:

```
Text(
    countryCodeToEmoji("TR"),
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
       ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this mapper is help anyone who is looking a solution like me.Thanks to chat-gpt to generate list :)

langToFlag.dart

```
const  Map<String, String> languageFlags = {
  "English": "",
  "Chinese": "",
  "Spanish": "",
  "Hindi": "",
  "Arabic": "",
  "Bengali": "",
  "Portuguese": "",
  "Russian": "",
  "Japanese": "",
  "Punjabi": "",
  "German": "",
  "French": "",
  "Javanese": "",
  "Telugu": "",
  "Marathi": "",
  "Vietnamese": "",
  "Korean": "",
  "Tamil": "",
  "Urdu": "",
  "Turkish": "",
  "Italian": "",
  "Egyptian Arabic": "",
  "Ukrainian": "",
  "Polish": "",
  "Malayalam": "",
  "Kannada": "",
  "Gujarati": "",
  "Oriya": "",
  "Thai": "",
  "Malay": "",
  "Nepali": "",
  "Dutch": "",
  "Sinhala": "",
  "Somali": "",
  "Romanian": "",
  "Kazakh": "",
  "Chhattisgarhi": "",
  "Khmer": "",
  "Magahi": "",
  "Assamese": "",
  "Haryanvi": "",
  "Hungarian": "",
  "Chittagonian": "",
  "Deccan": "",
  "Azerbaijani": "",
  "Rohingya": "",
  "Greek": "",
  "Zhuang": "",
  "Czech": "",
  "Tajik": "",
  "Catalan": "",
  "Zulu": "",
  "Finnish": "",
  "Haitian Creole": "",
  "Hebrew": "",
  "Serbian": "",
  "Swedish": "",
  "Uyghur": "",
  "Sindhi": "",
  "Kikuyu": "",
  "Hmong": ""
  // Add more languages and their corresponding flag emojis here
}
```

Example usage:

```
Text(
                            languageFlags[language] ?? "",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          )
```