# how to show country flag using it's name in pre lollipop

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to show country flag using it's name like "IR" , "US" ,"CN", ...
I used below code but it does not work in android 5.1.1 and below and it's just shows "IR" instead of flag. [my code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpWwT.png)
so any body can help me?

```
fun getCountryEmoji(country: String): String {
    val flagOffset = 0x1F1E6
    val asciiOffset = 0x41
    val firstChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 0) - asciiOffset + flagOffset
    val secondChar = Character.codePointAt(country, 1) - asciiOffset + flagOffset
    val flag = String(Character.toChars(firstChar)) + String(Character.toChars(secondChar))
    return flag
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50963795/1193179

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram i said that i used it and it didn't worked correct. look at my code.