# how to get country flag image with country name using timezone

Tags: android, gridview, timezone, flags, country-codes

I'm new to android and developing an app which shows the country list with its flag in a GridView, I'm using `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` to get the countries name, but don't have any idea how to get the flag images.
Can anyone tell me how to get the flags with country name or using country code.

Comment: check this answer [Android Countries list with....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519675/android-countries-list-with-flags-and-availability-of-getting-iso-mobile-codes)

Answer (score 0):

You have few ways of doing it.

**1.** Create a `Hashmap` in which you will keep country name and image, and according to country name fetch your image from HashMap.

**2.** If you have images in your `drawable` folder then keep image name same according to the name that you will get from TimeZone and then load that particular image from drawable folder.

Comment: You have to keep it somewhere