# Android ISO country code and flag assets

Tags: android, assets, iso, mobile-country-code

I'm looking for assets that map ISO country codes to flag images in different resolutions, something like [this](https://github.com/madebybowtie/FlagKit) but for Android.
It seems as if the project in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20519676/1016118) answer provides the necessary assets, but unfortunately the link to the project is broken.

Comment: have a look this [link](https://github.com/WANGjieJacques/flagkit) The author does mention its a copy of the flagkit you have shown the link to

Comment: A more robust library can be found [here](https://github.com/blongho/world-country-flags) **Disclaimer:** I am creator of that library. Feel free to make a pull request if something is lacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chirag90's comment providing [this link](https://github.com/WANGjieJacques/flagkit) is the resource I was looking for. Please note that when using this library the iso code needs to be passed in lowercase letters, otherwise, the resource is not found, leading to a crash.